# Memento Pattern implementation

Tags: java, design-patterns

I had just finished work on the [Memento Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern), and now I want to hear your feedback on it.

```
public class Caretaker {

    List<Originator.Memento> snapshots;

    public Caretaker() {
        this.snapshots = new ArrayList<Originator.Memento>();
    }

    public Caretaker(List<Originator.Memento> snapshots) {
        this.snapshots = snapshots;
    }

    public void addSnapshot(Originator.Memento memento) {
        snapshots.add(memento);
    }

    public List<Originator.Memento> getSnapshots() {
        return snapshots;
    }

    public Originator.Memento find(Criteria criteria, Object key) {
        switch (criteria) {
            case ByCode:
                for (Originator.Memento state : snapshots) {
                    if (state.getCode().equals(key)) {
                        return state;
                    }
                }
                break;
            case ByState:
                for (Originator.Memento state : snapshots) {
                    if (state.getState().equals(key)) {
                        return state;
                    }
                }
                break;
            case ByParameterKey:
                for (Originator.Memento state : snapshots) {
                    if (state.getParameters().containsKey(key)) {
                        return state;
                    }
                }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And of course the `Originator` class:

```
public class Originator {

    private String state;
    private Integer code;
    private Map<String, String> parameters;

    /**
     * We have only setter here for security purposes (encapsulation). I mean we don't need
     * to provide any access to the secret state for anybody.
     */
    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public void setCode(Integer code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public void setParameters(Map<String, String> parameters) {
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }

    public Memento save() {
        return new Memento(this);
    }

    public void restore(Memento memento) {
        this.state = memento.getState();
        this.code = memento.getCode();
        this.parameters = memento.getParameters();
    }

    /**
     * We use Memento class for making a snapshot of Originator state.
     */
    public class Memento {
        private String state;
        private Integer code;
        private Map<String, String> parameters;

        public Memento(Originator o) {
            Cloner cloner = new Cloner();
            this.state = cloner.deepClone(o.state);
            this.code = cloner.deepClone(o.code);
            this.parameters = cloner.deepClone(o.parameters);
        }

        /**
         * Here we have only getters. This is a narrow interface which provides
         * access only for clone of state.
         */
        public String getState() {
            return state;
        }

        public Integer getCode() {
            return code;
        }

        public Map<String, String> getParameters() {
            return parameters;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Originator{" +
                "state='" + state + '\'' +
                ", code=" + code +
                ", parameters=" + parameters +
                '}';
    }
}
```

`Criteria` enum:

```
public enum Criteria {
    ByState,
    ByCode,
    ByParameterKey
}
```

Test launcher:

```
public class AppRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Originator originator = new Originator();

        /**
         * Setup an originator
         */
        originator.setCode(100);
        originator.setState("active");
        originator.setParameters(new HashMap<String, String>() {{
            put("key1", "value1");
            put("key2", "value2");
        }});

        /**
         * Changing and saving with Memento the states of Originator
         */
        Caretaker caretaker = new Caretaker();
        caretaker.addSnapshot(originator.save());
        System.out.println(originator);

        originator.setCode(500);
        caretaker.addSnapshot(originator.save());
        System.out.println(originator);

        originator.setCode(1500);
        caretaker.addSnapshot(originator.save());
        System.out.println(originator);

        /**
         * We even could make some search with Caretaker
         */
        Originator.Memento m = caretaker.find(Criteria.ByCode, 500);

        /**
         * And finally restoring an object
         */
        originator.restore(m);
        System.out.println(originator);
    }
}
```

I use a library for cloning state.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>uk.com.robust-it</groupId>
    <artifactId>cloning</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Is it a proper Memento Pattern implementation? But the main question is do I really need to provide the getters in Memento class or maybe I can use another approach?

Answer (score 3):

I think your implementation is fine, you followed the wiki well, but I would suggest some improvements.

#### Unit testing

Before we touch anything, let's convert `AppRunner` to a proper unit test, so we can make changes and check easily that we're not breaking anything:

```
public class MementoTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        Originator originator = new Originator();

        originator.setCode(500);
        originator.setState("active");
        originator.setParameters(new HashMap<String, String>() {{
            put("key1", "value1");
            put("key2", "value2");
        }});

        Caretaker caretaker = new Caretaker();
        caretaker.addSnapshot(originator.save());
        assertEquals(
                "Originator{state='active', code=500, parameters={key1=value1, key2=value2}}",
                originator.toString());

        originator.setCode(1500);
        originator.setState("pending");
        originator.setParameters(new HashMap<String, String>() {{
            put("key1", "value1+");
            put("key2", "value2+");
        }});

        caretaker.addSnapshot(originator.save());
        assertEquals(
                "Originator{state='pending', code=1500, parameters={key1=value1+, key2=value2+}}",
                originator.toString());

        assertEquals(
                "Originator{state='pending', code=1500, parameters={key1=value1+, key2=value2+}}",
                originator.toString());

        Originator.Memento m = caretaker.find(Criteria.ByCode, 500);
        originator.restore(m);
        assertEquals(
                "Originator{state='active', code=500, parameters={key1=value1, key2=value2}}",
                originator.toString());
    }
}
```

I added more `set*` actions because the original method was testing only the code. In particular, the parameters map is the most interesting.

*This is by no means a great unit test, it's just for the sake of keeping the current implementation intact.*

#### You don't need the Cloner

Due to the way you implemented the setters on `Originator`, you don't need to clone anything. Consider for example the potentially most tricky one:

> ```
> public void setParameters(Map<String, String> parameters) {
>     this.parameters = parameters;
> }
> ```

You are replacing `this.parameters`. Had you implemented it this way:

```
public void setParameters(Map<String, String> parameters) {
    this.parameters.clear();
    this.parameters.putAll(parameters);
}
```

This way you *would have needed* the deep cloning, but this is not the case.

The same goes for `state` and `code` as well.

So in fact you could simplify the `Memento` constructor using simple assignments:

```
public Memento(Originator o) {
    this.state = o.state;
    this.code = o.code;
    this.parameters = o.parameters;
}
```

#### Getters or not

> But the main question is do I really need to provide the getters in Memento class or maybe I can use another approach?

Another approach can be to get rid of the getters, and make all fields `public final` in `Memento`:

```
public final String state;
public final Integer code;
public final Map<String, String> parameters;
```

Since the fields are `final`, there's no harm in making them `public`, and it's simpler to access them directly. The downside is if you ever want to extend this class and override these fields. Then you would have to bring back the getters.

#### Naming

> ```
> case ByCode:
>     for (Originator.Memento state : snapshots) {
>         if (state.getState().equals(key)) {
>             return state;
>         }
>     }
> ```

It's a minor thing, but instead of calling the loop variable `state`, perhaps `snapshot` would be better, especially since the Originator has a `state` field:

```
case ByState:
    for (Originator.Memento snapshot : snapshots) {
        if (snapshot.getState().equals(key)) {
            return snapshot;
        }
    }
```

#### Implement searching elsewhere

As you yourself have noticed, the `find` method doesn't seem to fit well with the rest of the class. It seems it just doesn't belong there. As much as possible, it's best when a class does only one thing. In this case the Caretaker should store snapshot, and do nothing else.

If you want to search in the snapshots, you could move that functionality to another class. It will be a more extensible configuration, because you will be able to rewrite the searching logic in different ways without changing the Caretaker.

#### More unit tests

The Memento pattern is not easy. Add more unit tests to cover your back.

Comment: Frankly I agree with guys from GOF, when they say, that  *The Caretaker provides storage only; it should neither examine nor modify the contents of the Memento object*. Now I see why it's so important. When I use `find()` method it breaks all the point of `Memento Pattern` (encapsulation).

Comment: And of cause all fields of Memento should be private.

Comment: That's an excellent observation! It's best when a class does only one thing. In this case it stores snapshots. And as you noticed, the `find` method doesn't seem to belong. If you want to find snapshots, you could move that functionality to another class. It will be a more extensible configuration, because you can rewrite the finding logic in different ways without ever touching the Caretaker.

Comment: In fact your point is so good I added a new section for it in my post, see near the end.